# float, int and str to byte array - python

Tags: python, arrays

I need to convert floats, ints and strings to byte arrays. This is Python2.7.

I know how to do this with floats and ints (for **floats only**, for example, `struct.pack("{}f".format(len(float_array)), float_array)`) and with strings I am assuming one would just do `list((map(ord, string)) for string in str_list)`.

So, is there a way to do this for everything if it is all muddled up together. At the very minumum, I would like to be able to mix floats and ints together without having to iterate through each one.

If I *do* have to iterate through each one, how can I do this quickly and effectively. (Note: I have to run through a list of data - each datum of which, for now, is either a float or an int, however I also know which index should be either an int or a float (but I shouldn't need to know this) - and it would be preferable to simply take the list and convert it to another list of byte arrays (or really just a string like "\xasdf\xadf\xasdf") in one fell swoop.)

Example: `[1, 1.0]` ==> byte array (or more complex `[1, 1.0, "a"] ==> bytearray`)

Note: I get an error when I do this:

```
import struct
num_list = [1, 1.0]
num_struct = struct.pack("2f", num_list)
```

but not when I do this:

```
import struct
num_list = [1.0, 2.0]
num_struct = struct.pack("2f", num_list)
```

Comment: It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please **give example input and output** needed and *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this.

Comment: I have a list of ints/floats (`[1, 1.0]`); I want a list of similar length represented as a byte array **and** I would like to not have to check if each one is an int or a float in a for loop.

Comment: It's still not obvious what you want; what do you mean by "bytearray"?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/bytearray.html

Comment: If you downvote explain why.

Comment: I know what a `bytearray` is. Would this do `lambda x: bytearray()`? If not, please explain *what you actually want*.

Comment: See edit. I don't have a byte array. I have a list on floats and ints, and I would like to convert that to a byte arrays (like "\x$a\xasf" nonsense)

Comment: @Veedrac If you have a list of floats, for example, and you do what I did above (`struct.pack("#f", float_list)`), then you get a byte array. I would like to do that with both floats and ints with no error.

Comment: This sounds like the most absurd thing to want to do. How do you get the data *back* if you're just encoding it?

Comment: @Veedrac putting it into klv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def pack_all(lst):
    fmt = ''.join('i' if isinstance(x, int) else 'd' for x in lst)
    return struct.pack(fmt, *lst)
```

This handles integers and floats (double size). Strings are probably best handled with `encode` separately.

Comment: thanks. I guess; luckily I just found a way to only have floats. thanks

Comment: Oh and I had another error so pack actually handles ints and floats... jynx